# React Redux source function ensureCanMutateNextListeners？

Tags: reactjs, redux

how to understand function ensureCanMutateNextListeners？
https://github.com/reactjs/redux/blob/master/src/createStore.js

Answer (score 2):

Posting relevant sections obtained from [Aaron Powell's blog post here](http://www.aaron-powell.com/posts/2016-06-09-learning-redux-with-reducks-creating-a-store.html)

Sample implementation of `subscribe` function from `redux`

```
let subscriptions = [];
const subscribe = function (fn) {
    if (typeof fn !== 'function') {
        throw Error('The provided listener must be a function');
    }

    var subscribed = true;

    // This line is what we are interested in
    subscriptions.push(fn);

    return function () {
        if (!subscribed) {
            return;
        }

        var index = subscriptions.indexOf(fn);
        subscriptions.splice(index, 1);
        subscribed = false;
    };
};
```

For every `dispatch` performed, we must notify every `subscriber`.

From the blog

> Now one thing you might want to add to the subscribe function is mutation hold on the subscribers collection. The reason for this that you want the collection of listeners shouldn't change while a dispatch is running.

Continued ...

> So here we have a function **ensureCanMutateNextListeners** that, when invoked, checks if the two arrays are the same array reference, if they are, use slice to clone currentSubscriptions so that when we modify the nextSubscriptions array (adding or removing a listener) it **won't impact any currently running dispatch pipeline**. The goal here is to **ensure** that the **listeners** that are used by dispatch are a **point in time**, for when the dispatch started.

Comment: Aaron Powell's blog post here: https://www.aaron-powell.com/posts/2016-06-09-learning-redux-with-reducks-creating-a-store/

I actually have another question about this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45746097/alternative-implementations-of-redux-source-function-ensurecanmutatenextlistener

Answer (score 1):

This question has been troubling me for quite some while, while the answer and blog post above offers the core idea, it doesn't give a concrete example.

My thinking process was: javaScript is single threaded, any function has run to completion behavior - so it doesn't really make sense to say `subscribe` has to worry whether there's a current dispatch operation going on. If we are inside function `subscribe`, it's literally impossible to be also inside `dispatch`: as nowhere inside the body of `subscribe` is `dispatch` being called, directly or indirectly.

With that said I just realized a flaw in the above logic today, and thought I'd share here. The explanation is while inside `subscribe`, `dispatch` will not be running, but the reverse is not true. `subscribe` (and `unsubscribe`) could be running inside `dispatch`. Here's source of `dispatch`:

```
  function dispatch(action) {
    // ...

    const listeners = currentListeners = nextListeners
    for (let i = 0; i < listeners.length; i++) {
      const listener = listeners[i]
      listener()
    }

    return action
  }
```

Looks innocent enough right? Notice the short line: `listener()`. `listener` is supplied by user of `redux`, and literally can be any function - including `subscribe` (or a function calls `store.subscribe`). Finally, Here's an actual example:

```
const store = createStore(someReducer);

function doSubscribe() {
  store.subscribe(doSubscribe);
}
doSubscribe();
```

Now what happens when we dispatch? Suppose `ensureCanMutateNextListeners` is not used, and `subscribe` actually push listener to `currentListeners` mutablly.

```
store.dispatch(action);
```

Will loop through all listeners:

```
for (let i = 0; i < listeners.length; i++) {
  const listener = listeners[i]
  listener()
}
```

Initially there's only one listener: `listeners === [doSubscribe]`, so we call `listener[0`], a.k.a `doSubscribe`, which calls `store.subscribe` and will push function `doSubscribe` to `listeners`, now `listeners` have two items! So the loop will call the second function `listeners[1]`, which adds another `listener`, now we have three items... Because `doSubscribe` subscribes itself, the loop will keeps on going, and run forever! Of course, a fix to prevent this particular infinite loop can be:

```
const currentListenersCount = listeners.length;
for (let i = 0; i < currentListenersCount; i++) {
  const listener = listeners[i]
  listener()
}
```

But there can be other situations that mutates listeners array in unexpected way by some `listener` even if using only `redux` public api.

Therefore, `ensureCanMutateNextListeners` is introduced as a general solution. Inside dispatch, any indirect call to `subscribe` and `unsubscribe` (only two public functions `redux` allows you to modify listeners) will mutate a copy of `currentListeners` - producing more predictable behaviors. In the example above, with the use of `ensureCanMutateNextListeners`, `doSubscribe` will add a add itself to a **copy** of `listeners` when called, the loop in `dispatch` remain unaffected and complete without any issues.

Comment: Digging redux docs today, realized the official API documentation does explain this a bit: https://github.com/reactjs/redux/blob/master/docs/api/Store.md#subscribelistener

> The subscriptions are snapshotted just before every dispatch() call. If you subscribe or unsubscribe while the listeners are being invoked, this will not have any effect on the dispatch() that is currently in progress. However, the next dispatch() call, whether nested or not, will use a more recent snapshot of the subscription list.

Answer (score 0):

It's a good question. Call @gaearon here